# Octal Value Assigning it to int

Tags: java

In a quiz I found one question where i need to calculate out of below program

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    short x = 0;
    int b = 08; 
    x +=b;

    System.out.println("" + b + x );
}
```

It gives compilation error on

```
 int b = 08;
```

As it an octal value, So I tried some different values

```
 int b = 07 // working fine (decimal of same is 7)
 int b = 08 // (Decimal value 8) // Compilation error
 int b = 09 // (Decimal value 9) // Compilation error
 int b = 010 // (Decimal value 8) // No Compilation error
```

As 08 and 010 have same decimal number then why 08 gives compilation error.

Comment: In binary we don't have a digit for 2. In Hex, there is no digit for 16, and so is for decimal, there is no single digit for the value 10. For any base b, the digits we have will be `0` till `b-1` which makes 'b' number of digits. For octal, we don't have 8 as a digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in *octal* notation, `010` != `08`. Actually, `08` doesn't exist in *octal number system*. All you can use are numbers `0-7` (starting with a `0`).

Answer (score 4):

All the integer literals, which start with `0`, are considered as octal.

Octal numbers, however, can consist of the digits from `0` to `7`, inclusive.

That's why you get a compilation error for `08` and `09`, but not for `010`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because octal notation can only contain digits `0,1,2,3,4,5,6` and `7`.

When you start your integer literal with `0`, you mark it as an octal number. But the digit `8` is invalid in octal notation, hence the compiler gives the error.

For example, decimal `8` is written in octal as `010`, and decimal `9` is `011` in octal.

Answer (score 2):

Just because there's no digit `8` in octal. You have only 8 different digits: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

From [JLS jls-OctalNumeral](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-OctalNumeral)

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.
>
> **OctalDigit:**
> (one of)
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

That's why you getting  a compilation error for `08` and `09`